# What questions are on and off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Yes, I presume this is probably a duplicate post, but I can't seem to find a list of on and off topic material here.  I searched this meta looking, and found asking if their particular idea was on of off topic, and some people asking why their question was closed, but I can't find ***the list*** of on-topic questions.

Is there a way to pin it to the top of a set of search terms?  For example "on topic", "What is on topic?".

Comment: You have read all the useful info and faq's under that little help link at the top, right? Check out http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would suggest reading the help pages.  That also gets you the Informed badge.